# how to display date in set timezone using angular2

Tags: angular2-template

how to display date in set time

> {{ mydate | date : DATE_FORMAT.DD_MMM_YYYY : 'America/New_York'}}
>   not working.

Comment: @ Bharti,, date in DD MM YYYY format? Is that you need?

Comment: yes need date formate .

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this, it worked for me

in your component,

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

private myDate:any = new Date();

constructor() {

    if(this.myDate != ""){                                
       this.myDate = new DatePipe("en-US").transform(this.myDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
    }else{
       this.myDate = "";
    }
}
```

In your html,

```
<div> {{myDate}} </div> /* you get your date in dd-mm-yyyy format*/
```

Hope this helps

Comment: {{ mydate | date : DATE_FORMAT.DD_MMM_YYYY : 'anytimezone'}} not working.

Comment: you dont have to give {{ mydate | date : DATE_FORMAT.DD_MMM_YYYY : 'anytimezone'}} ,,, you only needed {{myDate}} to work your code. 

NB: pls check the variable name, i have used {{myDate}}, you should use your date variable name. Thanks :)

Comment: i getting your point but my exact issue is Display date need to convert anytimezone which i set in setting .
for Exp. if i set timezone 'Africa/Nairobi' so display date in Africa/Nairobi this timzone and set other timzeone so date display other timezone.
my date saved in Mongodb Database.